# Rospack error after switching to fuerte

Tags: ros-fuerte, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,
i recently installed Fuerte and tried to build a package (including services and action-file) that i use in Electric. I get the following error:

```
  (...)
  [rosbuild] Building package morsetesting
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only morsetesting
  Package geometry_msgs was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `geometry_msgs.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'geometry_msgs' found
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
  (...)
```

It says it cannot find geometry_msgs, but if i do a "rospack find geometry_msgs", it returns the path to the geometry_msgs ROS package that only contains the msg-files. Shouldn't it return the patch to the python-files that are now in `/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geometry_msgs/`? Or am i missing something here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33356/rospack-error-after-switching-to-fuerte/) by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-05-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-05-06**:
After switching back to Electric it works find after a "make clean". I use a fresh shell for everything at the moment as recommended..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, i found out something interesting. I had an overlay of common_msgs that somehow caused to fail using rosws. When i removed common_msgs using rosws remove, i could build the package again...

But adding an overlay of common_msgs reproduces the same error ( No package 'geometry_msgs' found ).

I'll open a new question for this issue...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your Fuerte `setup.bash` is probably wrong. Unlike previous releases, you can't just substitute `fuerte` for `electric` in the setup script or in the `.rosinstall` for your workspace.

Try building a new workspace using an updated `rosinstall` (or its new `rosws` command). I can provide details if you need them.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-05-06**:
I actually used rosws to create the workspace and rosinstall to install the stack...

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-05-06**:
Just to make sure, i set up the whole setup again. First "rosws init ./fuerte /opt/ros/fuerte" then used "rosws merge to add the packages". But still the same error... maybe i should mention, the package i am trying to build only contains service- and action-definitions and no actual source-code...